# Read a functions response from other page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function SaveData which is basically an API request.

```js
export function SaveData(data, initialState) {
    try {
        axios.post("http://192.168.1.17:85/DevAPINew/API/" + initialState.SaveUrl, data[0])
            .then(response => console.log(response))
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

I am calling this function in another page.
How can i read the response from another page

`SaveData(data, initialState)`

Comment: why don't you try adding the response to redux store and then access it where ever you want in the application

Comment: export function SaveData(data, initialState) { 
try { 
axios.post("http://192.168.1.17:85/DevAPINew/API/" + initialState.SaveUrl, data[0]) .then(response => return response;) 
}
.catch (error) { 
return error; 
} 
}


and simply do 

let resp = SaveData(data, initialState);
console.log(resp);

Comment: It is undefined @HamzaKhan

Comment: If it's just a component then use props otherwise use either context or redux (or any other library)

Comment: Can you please edit the question and show the component where you call `SaveData()` and also the other one in which you wanted to access the data? .

Comment: Ummm... what do you mean by accessing a response from "another page"? Did you mean calling the function from another page? It's not possible to access to result of running JavaScript from another open page. You could, however, (if I understood your question correctly) send a request to the server which notifies the other client... (with the help of stuff like WebSockets)